# How can I enable `cairo` backend while plotting `igraph` objects on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, backend, igraph

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and trying to make graphs of `igraph` appear on `matplotlib` plots. I've found that one of possible solutions is to create [`GraphArtist`](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2010-06/txtncWL6o4O3e.txt) class class that draws igraph graphs but, unfortunately, only Cairo-based backends are supported. When I try to use it, no plot is displayed

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("cairo")
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
plt.plot(range(10), [i**1.5 for i in range(10)]) #a simplified version of my diagram
plt.show()
```

and I get this warning:

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using cairo, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
```

And, indeed, I can see that it's not on the list:

```
>>> print ("Non Gui backends are:", matplotlib.rcsetup.non_interactive_bk)
>>> print ("Gui backends are", matplotlib.rcsetup.interactive_bk)
Non Gui backends are: ['agg', 'cairo', 'pdf', 'pgf', 'ps', 'svg', 'template']
Gui backends are: ['GTK3Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'MacOSX', 'nbAgg', 'Qt4Agg', 'Qt4Cairo', 'Qt5Agg', 'Qt5Cairo', 'TkAgg', 'TkCairo', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'WXAgg', 'WXCairo']
```

What can I do to enable this `cairo` backend?
Additional question: there is `matplotlib.use("cairo.pdf")` used in a [link](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2010-06/txtncWL6o4O3e.txt), can it affect an output of script there?

Comment: In the Python-igraph manual, the section [Installing igraph](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/install.html#igraph-on-windows) gives information about installing `cairo` for use with igraph.  These instructions worked for me.

Comment: It work for me too. However, this is quite limited. I'm trying to add axes and titles in multiple subplots with no luck while doing this in a documented way. I've also mentioned this issue in [igraph discourse group](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/how-to-draw-multiple-subplots-on-cairo-surface/423)