# How to deals with unknown label and edges in python graph

Tags: python, igraph

I have two arrays, a and b. I would like to draw the `networkx` graph that group the values together which are close to each other and label them accordingly. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Finding close pairs**

Your algorithm finds closest point of `b` to each point of `a` but you need to identify a list of them within some threshold for distance (which might be empty in most of cases). This can be achieved with an assist of `scipy.spatial.KDTree`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from itertools import chain
def nearby_pts(a, b, distance):
    # indices of close points of `b` for each point of `a`
    a_data, b_data = np.expand_dims(a, axis=1), np.expand_dims(b, axis=1)
    idx = KDTree(b_data).query_ball_point(a_data, r=distance)
    return idx
```

Then you can find edges that joins pairs of indices of close points from  `a` to `b`. This can't be vectorized fully but I made the best I can out of it:

```
def close_pairs(a, b, distance):
    pts = nearby_pts(a, b, distance).tolist()
    pts_flatten = list(chain(*pts))
    idx = np.repeat(np.arange(len(pts)), [len(n) for n in pts])
    return np.c_[idx, pts_flatten]
```

Output:

```
>>> close_pairs(a, b, distance=150)
[[0, 12], [1, 11], [2, 13], [3, 7], [5, 10], [5, 15], [6, 8], [7, 1], [8, 2], [9, 3], [9, 14], [10, 0], [11, 6], [12, 4], [13, 5], [13, 15], [14, 3], [15, 10]]
```

**Plotting a graph**

Now you're ready to create a graph from edges found but first you need to relabel a second section of nodes (`b`) not to be duplicated with `a` section. So you can just add `len(a)` to indices of nodes of `b` and that's it:

```
import igraph as ig

pairs_relabel = close_pairs(a, b, distance=150) + [0, len(a)]
g = ig.Graph(n = len(a) + len(b))
g.add_edges(pairs_relabel)

pal = ig.drawing.colors.ClusterColoringPalette(2) #number of colors used is 2
color = pal.get_many([0]*len(a)+[1]*len(b)) #tags of colors
labels = np.r_[a.astype(int), b.astype(int)] #labels are integral values of nodes

ig.plot(g, bbox=(500, 300), vertex_size=24, 
        vertex_color = color, vertex_label_size=9, vertex_label = labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. However, when I run this code, I am getting the following error '
File "C:\Users\rp603\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\igraph\drawing\utils.py", line 396, in __getattr__   raise TypeError("plotting not available")

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath Try to install `pycairo` from [unofficial binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) especially for plotting. You might also like to see my analysis of both `networkx` and `igraph` [here](https://github.com/loijord/Python/blob/master/graph_libraries.ipynb)

Comment: I already 'pycairo' in my system and when I re-run ur program. I am still getting this error. I installed 'pycairo' version: 1.19.1. Build channel: py38h63da52a_o. Can it be plotted with matplotlib library? if so how?

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath Sorry for a long wait. It could be probably an issue of python version. Since release of python-igraph 0.8 no unofficial binaries are needed. I've tested a script of my answer in a new conda environment at it worked: `conda create --name testigraph`; `conda install jupyter`; `conda install scipy`; `pip install python-igraph`; `python install pycairo`. My version of `pycairo` was chosen automatically: `pycairo-1.20.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath Matplotlib is not supported for `igraph`. I've done some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536495/how-can-i-enable-cairo-backend-while-plotting-igraph-objects-on-matplotlib) on this topic already. Moreover, usage of `cairo` surfaces are [not so flexible](https://igraph.discourse.group/t/how-to-draw-multiple-subplots-on-cairo-surface/423) in python, unlike R. Well, thankfully, at least it [supports](http://cneurocvs.rmki.kfki.hu/igraph/screenshots2.html) that small number of features.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I don't know why but I am not able to work with 'pycairo'. However, I tried to use 'networkx' of python and it running fine though result look bit messy. I attached my code in my question. Could you please have a look and guide me where I am making mistake.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath Alright, so `networkx` is much easier but you losing performance. Try to avoid asking multiple questions in a single topic (implementation of algorithm and visual tools are different topics). Also you need to be more clear about expected output. What is the meaning of edges in your fig 2? Do they connect groups `a` and `b`? In my solution edges represent short distances between points from `a` and `b` and correspondences, is it sufficient? This might be only an issue of  layout.

Comment: @AnkitaDebnath Try to use `nx.Graph` instead of `nx.DiGraph`